# Unable to verify the CA signed SSL certificate python web server

Tags: python, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Here is the sample code for my python web server:

**Python web server code (not full version)**

```
class LogRequests(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        print("GET request received from {}".format(self.client_address[0]))
        self.write_response(200, {"success": True})

    def do_POST(self):
        print("GET request received from {}".format(self.client_address[0]))
        self.write_response(200, {"success": True})

    def write_response(self, status_code, json_body):
        self.send_response(status_code)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        self.write_json(json_body)


server = HTTPServer(('', 6000), LogRequests)

server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(server.socket, keyfile=<key-file-path>, certfile=<cert-file-path>, server_side=True)
server.serve_forever()
```

I'm having CA (Let's encrypt) signed certificate. I've also verified the validity of cert.pem and key.pem file with https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004119234-Verifying-the-validity-of-an-SSL-certificate.

**Postman request**:

```
URL: https://<hostname>:6000/
```

When I submit a POST or GET request it shows `SSL Error: Unable to verify the first certificate` error. But when I disable the `SSL certificate verification` from Postman settings, I'm able to make request and get response.

Can you guide me what can be wrong here? Is there any code issues?

Answer (score 0):

I got to find the solution myself.

Instead of the `cert.pem` file, I had to use the `fullchain1.pem` file.